# Change NFSv4 Bound Port?

Tags: nfs, port, nfs4

I need to use port 2049/tcp for another purpose. Is there a way to change which port NFSD binds to? I don't need NFSv3 or NFSv2 so I am not using rpcbind service. I cannot find that config option...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using just NFSv4 (no RPCBIND) you can change the port by adding `-p [port number]` to /etc/sysconfig/nfs RPCNFSDARGS and make sure it is uncommented.

I found this out by looking at `/etc/init.d/nfs`, I found this line:

```
echo -n $"Starting NFS daemon: "
daemon rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS $RPCNFSDCOUNT
```

I traced the definition of `$RPCNFSDARGS` back up to the top of the file, and saw /etc/sysconfig/nfs was loaded in. `man rpc.nfsd` revealed the -p option to specify the port.

My /etc/sysconfig/nfs now has the line:

```
RPCNFSDARGS="-p 2050 -N 2 -N 3"
```